# Returning text length of an element (jquery)

Tags: jquery, text, console, counter, calculator

I'm trying to stop a click event from appending to an html element when the character length is greater than 10, but I think I'm running into a syntax error I can't figure out.

(Just some more info. This is an optional calculator project, and there are probably way more elegant ways to do this, but we're supposed to give it a try without any real in depth JS/jQuery learning.) Here's my jsFiddle that I'm using to test code before putting it in my files.

I figured the easiest way was to push each number into one element (screen-relay), then grab the whole thing and apply eval(). I'm trying to get the console to report when it registers the char limit going over 10, but I'm not receiving anything. Thanks for the pointers!
(edit: because manners)

https://jsfiddle.net/vx09p7kk/

```js
// Evaluate value of screen

$("#equals").click(function() {
  var x = ($("#screen-relay").text());
  var finalValue = eval(x);

  console.log(finalValue);

  $("#output").html(finalValue);
});

// Clear Function

$("#clear").click(function() {
  ($("#screen-relay, #output").text(""));
});

// Char Limit Function

var CharCount = ($("#screen-relay").text().length);
if(CharCount > 10) {
  console.log(bam)
};
```

Comment: screen-relay is input box?

Comment: why not use maxlength attr?

Comment: CharCount is only evaluated once, at the very beginning. Put it into your click handler.

Comment: @DharaParmar Yep, that's right

Comment: then use $("#screen-relay").val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please take a look at below updated fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/vx09p7kk/4/

I have simply added a counter `totalCharEntered` which is getting incremented on each char insertion and getting cleared when we click on clear button:

```
// Buttons
var totalCharEntered = 0;
$("#one").click(function() {
  if(totalCharEntered <10){
    $("<span>1</span>").appendTo("#screen-relay");
    totalCharEntered++;
   }
});
$("#two").click(function() {
    if(totalCharEntered <10){
    $("<span>2</span>").appendTo("#screen-relay");
    totalCharEntered++;
   }
});
$("#plus").click(function() {
    if(totalCharEntered <10){
    $("<span>+</span>").appendTo("#screen-relay");
    totalCharEntered++;
   }
});

// Clear Function

$("#clear").click(function() {
  ($("#screen-relay, #output").text(""));
  totalCharEntered = 0;
});
```

I think it will help you a bit.

Comment: Brilliant, I've seen that in an array loop before but hadn't thought of that. Thank you very much.
edit: If any of the other contributors check back, thank you as well, I was trying all your suggestions.